# How to make Map Package on QGIS?

Tags: qgis, mapping, map-package

I will save my project into Map Package so I can share with another user. Using ArcGIS I can easily make Map Package as .mxd but I don't know how to do that on QGIS.

So how to make Map Package on QGIS?

Comment: what is the definition of a map package ?

Comment: You can use [QPackage](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/QPackage/version/1.5/) or [QConsolidate3](https://github.com/danzig666/qconsolidate3).

Comment: Ok, thank you @Kadir Sahbaz. i'll try it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If a **folder** can fit your definition of a map package you're able to use the plug-in **QPackage** that will relocate all of the layers contained in a projet in order to make it a "portable" one ...

*(this plug-in takes in account all the layers of your QGIS projects regardless of their source type : for example if you have postgis sources they will be exported by the plug-in as shape files ...)*